# Accessing properties from PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with multiple property files

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I am new to spring (3.1) and totally stumped by this problem. 
I am trying to access a property value "schdestination" using a **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** that is defined in two property files (one overriding the other).

I want to use @Value to set a field in a class and i just can't find a way to do it without using another bean. Here is my spring XML snippet

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/abc.properties</value>
            <value>/WEB-INF/loc.abc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

Any clues please?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Value("${schdestination}")
private String destination;
```

should work.

Comment: this is what i am trying but somehow the string value comes back: that is the variable destination has value of "${schdestination}" and not the path from property file..

Comment: in what xml file is the configurer defined?

Answer (score 0):

The class that contains the `@Value` needs to be annotated with `@Component` and you need to have `<context:component-scan/>` in your applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it in your web app? That was my case. I was loading property files from application context and somehow they were not visible in the web app package - controllers to be precise. I had to re-declare them in servlet-context.xml, then they are visible and work just fine. I am really hoping somebody might shed some light what could be going on, or whether it is truly an issue to be fixed in Spring.